# Airflow commands fail due to typeerror in utils.py when deployed in heroku

Tags: heroku, airflow, gunicorn

Im running airflow version 2.4.1 with python 3.10. I have no issues when running airflow locally in docker, but when I deploy it to heroku using their container registry, the `airflow webserver` command fails with this trackback:

```
  ____________       _____________
 ____    |__( )_________  __/__  /________      __
____  /| |_  /__  ___/_  /_ __  /_  __ \_ | /| / /
___  ___ |  / _  /   _  __/ _  / / /_/ /_ |/ |/ /
 _/_/  |_/_/  /_/    /_/    /_/  \____/____/|__/
Running the Gunicorn Server with:
Workers: 4 sync
Host: 0.0.0.0:55811
Timeout: 120
Logfiles: - -
Access Logformat: 
=================================================================
[2022-11-10 00:19:39 +0000] [43] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
    run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 67, in run
    WSGIApplication("%(prog)s [OPTIONS] [APP_MODULE]").run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 231, in run
    super().run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 72, in run
    Arbiter(self).run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 198, in run
    self.start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 138, in start
    self.cfg.on_starting(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/airflow/www/gunicorn_config.py", line 40, in on_starting
    ProvidersManager().connection_form_widgets
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/airflow/providers_manager.py", line 908, in connection_form_widgets
    self.initialize_providers_hooks()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/airflow/providers_manager.py", line 300, in wrapped_function
    func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/airflow/providers_manager.py", line 386, in initialize_providers_hooks
    self.initialize_providers_list()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/airflow/providers_manager.py", line 300, in wrapped_function
    func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/airflow/providers_manager.py", line 363, in initialize_providers_list
    self._discover_all_providers_from_packages()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/airflow/providers_manager.py", line 429, in _discover_all_providers_from_packages
    for entry_point, dist in entry_points_with_dist('apache_airflow_provider'):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/airflow/utils/entry_points.py", line 40, in entry_points_with_dist
    key = canonicalize_name(dist.metadata["Name"])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/packaging/utils.py", line 34, in canonicalize_name
    value = _canonicalize_regex.sub("-", name).lower()
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
[2022-11-10 00:21:38,935] {webserver_command.py:217} ERROR - No response from gunicorn master within 120 seconds
[2022-11-10 00:21:38,935] {webserver_command.py:218} ERROR - Shutting down webserver
```

Has anyone run into this error before? Let me know if more information is needed.

Answer (score 0):

I have just solved the problem, in my case I had packages where there weren't `NAME` field in `METADATA`.

First you can check it counting number of None:

```
import importlib_metadata as metadata
import pandas as pd
s = pd.Series([dist.metadata["Name"] for dist in metadata.distributions()])
s.isnull().sum()
```

After that, you need find what packages are causing your problem and uninstall and install it.

I solve it using `vscode` debugger with `justMycode: false`.

I was debugging the next code:

```
for met in metadata.distributions():
    print(met.name)
```

The point here is to add a `if condition` and a break point in the next path /`PATH/lib/PYTHON_VERSION/site-package/importlib_metadata/__init__.py`, for example in my case:

```
/home/antonio/anaconda3/Aspect-Based-On-Sentiment-Analysis/lib/python3.7/site-package/importlib_metadata/__init__.py
```

Set `if condition` and break point in `print('now')` (line 598):

```
@property
def name(self):
    """Return the 'Name' metadata for the distribution package."""
    if not self.metadata.json:
        print('now')
    return self.metadata['Name']
```

You could see on debug window something like that,

[image]

The field `_normalized_name` will indicate you package name that you need to uninstall since the rest of the fields will be `None` when name is `None`

May be `pip uninstall name_package` doesn't work.

I recommend you to search the package in `/PATH/lib/PYTHON_VERSION/site-package`, check NAME is not in `METADATA` file or `METADATA` file doesn't exist and remove the entire package, finally, you can use `pip install name-package` and check `NAME` is in `METADATA` file

Then you check number of packages without `NAME` in `METADATA` running:

```
import importlib_metadata as metadata
import pandas as pd
s = pd.Series([dist.metadata["Name"] for dist in metadata.distributions()])
s.isnull().sum()
```

You will see it has decreased by one.